# how to change a content inside of tab? [JS, JQUERY and HTML5]

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a tab with a specific content, inside of the tab i've got a link to another page, but I wanna load this page inside of the same tab, without use a back end. Here's an example:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <title>TEST</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1">A</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-2">B</a></li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-3">C</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1">
                <p>ABCDEF...</p>
                <a href="test.html">LOAD ANOTHER CONTENT IN THIS TAB HERE!</a>
            </div>
            <div id="tabs-2">2</div>
            <div id="tabs-3">3</div>
        </div>        
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $("#tabs").tabs();
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But the another content is a page .html, that's why I'm using a link to use href and try load the new content inside of the tab.

Any help?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/load/ -  this looks like a case for... jQuery! Start by reading this...

Comment: Look up jQuery `.load()` - it does exactly this

Comment: @Joum , Thanks, This was exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney , Thanks Too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as you have seen in the other answers, [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is the way to go.

You could call this when something happens, like a `click` event on a tab or something like that. For example, add something like this to your script:

```
$(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
});

$("#firstTab").on("click", function(){
  $("#tabs-1").load("dir/page.html");
});
```

Assuming you give the first tab in your HTML `id="firstTab"`, of course.

Comment: Joum, I used your code and I finished my code, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery's load:

```
$( "#tabs-1" ).load( "page.html");
```

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: Lucas, Thanks for the sintaxe and lib.

Answer (score 0):

By using bellow code you can load any url for particular tab by adding custom attribute data-load

http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">   </script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <li data-load="test-a.html"><a href="#tabs-1" >A</a></li>
            <li data-load="test-b.html"><a href="#tabs-2" >B</a></li>
            <li data-load="test-c.html"><a href="#tabs-3" >C</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <p>ABCDEF...</p>
            <a href="test.html">LOAD ANOTHER CONTENT IN THIS TAB HERE!</a>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">2</div>
        <div id="tabs-3">3</div>
    </div>        
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("#tabs").tabs({
              activate: function (event, ui) {
                 var url = $('.ui-tabs-active').data("load"),
                   containerId = $('.ui-tabs-active').find('a').attr("href"); 
                   $(containerId).load(url);

              }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please [avoid link only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info). Answers that are "barely more than a link to an external site” [may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).